# Remote desktop into iMac while someone is on a separate account?

Tags: imac, ssh, user-account, remote-desktop

I'm using an iMac 21.5-Inch (Late 2015). I have a son who has a full-time job, and his only option is to use our iMac.

Is there a way to remote desktop into my account while he's on his? If so, can I do this from my browser? [Shellngn](https://shellngn.com) is a website I use to ssh into devices. I need to do it from a browser because I'm unable to install apps, as I use a chromebook borrowed from the company I work at, and they disabled it.

I am programming iOS apps, and as you probably know, you can't do that on a chromebook. So I'd need to do this from Chrome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://superuser.com/questions/125636/can-a-mac-be-used-by-multiple-users-at-same-time

Comment: Partly. I'm still wondering if I can use my web browser for this.